# Print values to worksheet with Do While loop rather than using Immediate window

Tags: excel, algorithm, vba, do-while

I've learned that the "Immediate window" can only print up to 199 lines of values. Is there an easy way to print the values generated from the algorithm below to worksheet cells? Specifically, I am not sure if the `do while loop` is the most efficient way to do this. I usually deal with data already present on a worksheet and I just specify the loop to run until the last row with data. Since the outer most loop runs from `t=2 to 50`, I am not quite sure how to format the inner most loop to run until the algorithm has generated all possible values. As written, the macro was taking so long that I didn't wait for it to stop. The algorithm shouldn't generate more than a thousand lines of data at most.

```
For t = 2 To 50
    For b = 2 To 20
        For r = 1 To 20
            For k = 3 To 7
                If t * k = b * k Then
                lambda = r * (k - 1) / (t - 1)
                    If lambda = Int(lambda) Then
                        Do While t < 51
                        Cells(i, 1) = t
                        Cells(i, 2) = b
                        Cells(i, 3) = k
                        Cells(i, 4) = r
                        Cells(i, 5) = lambda
                        Debug.Print t, b, k, r, lambda
                        i = i + 1
                        Loop
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        Next r
    Next b
Next t
```

Comment: I am not getting. What exactly you want to do? Do you want to put `t, b, k, r, lambda` in one cell?

Comment: Value of `t` doesn't seem to change within the inner `Do While` loop ?  How does that loop ever exit?

Comment: You are already looping through everything.  The Do loop is not needed.  Remove it and put `i = range("A1000000000").end(xlup).offset(1).Row`

Comment: @ScottCraner my apologies, but I'm not exactly sure what you're saying to do. Like this? `i = Range("A1000000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row`, on the next line, `Cells(i, 1)`, then the next line `i = i + 1` I'm getting a global object failure.

Comment: @ScottCraner that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim and I have stated the do loop is not needed, It would go on forever.  So instead of a loop you need to dictate the row and then let it iterate.

```
For t = 2 To 50
    For b = 2 To 20
        For r = 1 To 20
            For k = 3 To 7
                If t * k = b * k Then
                lambda = r * (k - 1) / (t - 1)
                    If lambda = Int(lambda) Then
                        I = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                        Cells(I, 1) = t
                        Cells(I, 2) = b
                        Cells(I, 3) = k
                        Cells(I, 4) = r
                        Cells(I, 5) = lambda
                        'Debug.Print t, b, k, r, lambda
                        'I = I + 1

                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        Next r
    Next b
Next t
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the non-exiting loop problem, this will be faster:

```
Do While t < 51
    Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(t, b, k, r, lambda)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

If you need more speed-up then declare a 2-D array `arr(1 to [max # of rows], 1 to 5)`, populate it in the loop, and drop it on a worksheet:

```
 Range("a1").Resize([max # of rows],5).Value = arr
```

Comment: Much better approach.